# Non Consumable and Dynamic in app purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am having an issue implementing the kind of in-app purchase that my application demands, Basically we need to sell story books but the books and their prices are not fixed as the book list comes from some server. The price range is fixed i.e a book will be having price from this 3 prices(0.99$, 1.99$, 2.99$).Apple demands the purchase of books to be a non-consumable purchase, the issue is that we create 3 in-app purchase that I mentioned but there can be any number of books having the price 0.99$ but once we have purchased a book with in-app id of price 0.99$, if we purchase another book with same in-app ID it will say you have already purchased this item.We just want is to create a single in-app id and use them with multiple books of same price.Please help me out with some solution regarding this issue.

Comment: Can these books be used outside of the application?

Comment: Books are dynamic coming from the APIs they are not fix.

Comment: That is not what I asked.  I asked if the books themselves can be used outside of the application?

Comment: No the books will only be used within the app, that is it will be stored in local database.

Comment: @AlkeshFudani How did you end up solving this problem?

Answer (score 4):

For non-consumable in-app purchase you will need to create an in-app purchase code in iTunesConnect for each product. You can't use a generic product code as content purchases need to be restorable (and you would also have the problem that you pointed out of not being able to purchase more than one product at each price point).

Each content in-app purchasable item needs to be submitted to Apple for approval.

Comment: I don't believe that you can using in-app purchase.  You can have your users purchase through a web site and then log into their account from your app - This is what the Kindle app does, for example.  Note that you cannot provide access to your web-based store or account registration through the app or you will most likely get a rejection

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to let users purchase virtual currencies in your app. Then let them use those currencies to buy your books. In this case, you don't have to worry about the dynamic price and all you have is a single IAP item(currencies). But your server has to handle the purchase history carefully.

Not sure if this helps, i am dealing with the same problem in subscription items.

Comment: But as I mentioned in my case I was having books, so buying credits/coins is not suitable for the app. So for now I have kept the number of items static and created in-app for each of them, will have to rethink during the further enhancement of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create three consumables IAPs; a 'One dollar book' consumable, a 'two dollar book' consumable and a 'three dollar book' consumable.  Each consumable can be used by the user to download (or otherwise secure access to) one book in that price category.  Alternatively you could just sell Tokens and require that the user cash in 1,2 or 3 Tokens to buy a book in each of the three (or more) categories.  You would need to keep track of the user's purchases or create some way of allowing the user to transfer rights from one device to another device.  iCloud (each App has a key-value object) is good at managing that.